# How to remove text before brackets in java script

Tags: javascript

i want remove  'L.tileLayer.wms, ,'url_geoserver, words from below code.
or convert 'layers' key value into as a variable.

```
var url_test = L.tileLayer.wms('localhost:8020/geoserver/apb_cadal/wms',{
          layers: 'apb_cada:sankpl',

        });

var defaultParameters = {

            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: layers,
            outputFormat: 'application/json',
            format_options: 'callback:getJson'
};
```

From var url_test there is a key name is 'layers' and value name is 'apb_cada:sankpl', i want replace key name is 'typeName' with 'layers' value  in the var defaultParameters.  so i am planning is convert key name is 'layers ' as a variable like example  var layers = 'apb_cada:sankpl' 
then i can replace like typeName:layers

Comment: If the code is working, then why change it? If it is not working, then please explain what the problem is.

Comment: i want to make as a json object from that i can get layers as variable.

Comment: else if (gwc == 6032)
      {
        var url = L.tileLayer.wms(url_geoserver,{
          layers: 'ap_cadastl:sank',   
        })
      }    from the above statement  i want replace layers value with 'typeName' in the below statement var defaultParameters = {

            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: layers,
            outputFormat: 'application/json',
            format_options: 'callback:getJson'
};

Comment: Please add that to your question. It is confusing what you are asking. Please give an example of the url value set in your example above and we can help show you how to get the value from it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to shorten the writing length of your code in that statement, you can could make a function `getUrl()` which would contain that code and return the corresponding value:

```js
function getUrl() {
    return L.tileLayer.wms(url_geoserver,{
        layers: 'apb_cad:sanka',
    });
}

var url = getUrl();
```